# The thread-safe / multithreading tag synonyms need a cleanup

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There's a bit of strange synonym relationship with these tags on Stack Overflow:

- [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) ← [thread-safe](/questions/tagged/thread-safe) (and seven of others)
- [thread-safety](/questions/tagged/thread-safety) ← [threadsafe](/questions/tagged/threadsafe)

I was about to suggest [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) ← [thread-safety](/questions/tagged/thread-safety), but that doesn't work:

> [image]

If [thread-safety](/questions/tagged/thread-safety) and [threadsafe](/questions/tagged/threadsafe) are synonymous for tagging purposes, and [thread-safe](/questions/tagged/thread-safe) and [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) likewise, surely we can get a bit of transitivity going on here, hyphen notwithstanding?

---

Now with ***new and improved*** error popup:

> [image]

And trying to do this opposite is even more instructive (or not?):

> [image]

Comment: Hmmm; an edit was done here just now, but no hand-drawn circles were added. Y u no add hand-drawn circles?!?! ;)

Comment: i add flashy thing. ok naow? kthks

Comment: Oooh! Yes, definitely!!

Comment: woah flashy thing!1!!1!!one!! must upvote

Comment: 1.25 times: more than once, less than twice.

Answer (score 1):

This highlights a known bug with the tag synonym system.  I just had to deal with it in [my synonym request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212662/tag-synonym-for-edit-edits-and-editing).  It'll take a moderator to implement the needed changes.

I agree that [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) should rule them all.