# Can we get a better view of newly created tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, 10k-tools

The `/tools` route shows you a list of the 30 (?) newest tags on the site, including how often they've been used.

Now, this is nice information to have, and occasionally I check the route to kill off meaningless tags before they're getting used too much. However, it seems I'm only one of the very few people on Super User who do that.

[image]

Since the list only shows 30 tags, it's a little hard to analyze properly. You can't see *when* the tag was created and *who* created it. (Let's face it: There are some people who have a passion for creating meaningless tags.) Also, you have to remove a tag in that list before the next one shows up, which is a little tedious.

For example. in the above list, I had to kill [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged), [ubunut](/questions/tagged/ubunut) and [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) before I even saw [dedup](/questions/tagged/dedup) and [column-mode](/questions/tagged/column-mode).

Could moderators (and 10k users?) please get a table of the newest tags that'd allow them to see more than 30 at once, and also including the information who created the tag?

This would allow for much easier maintenance, even when you forget to do it for the last 30 days and have no way to check tags that were created, say 31 days ago.

Comment: `site.com/tags?tab=new` ([demo](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new)) has a bit more than 30 day's worth (~50?), and the creation date. Doesn't have creator though.

Comment: Cool, never noticed that. Also funny how SO users seem to take care of tag wikis when creating new tags. [People don't seem to care too much on SU](http://superuser.com/tags?tab=new). A tabular view would still be nice, since you could sort by usage or creator.

Comment: The tag pages need some serious love by a designer IMO. Finding the page that lists the proposed tag synonyms you can actually vote on is surprisingly difficult in particular.

Comment: Yes, the whole tag system is quite hard to maintain. The tools are scattered across so many pages, and there's no incentive for users to participate in cleaning up. Moderators can't even mass-untag, or mass-retag questions properly, et cetera. If you don't have a handful of people watching the tags, everything will get chaotic after time.

Comment: `<plug>`And even [superbe support requests on tags get ignored despite having _huge_ amounts of meta-rep on offer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150128/the-thread-safe-multithreading-tag-synonyms-need-a-cleanup)`</plug>`. (sorry for the comment spam :-) )