# Tag synonym for 'edit', 'edits' and 'editing'

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, meta, synonym-request

The tag [edits](/questions/tagged/edits) was synonymed already to [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) (though I think it would have been better the other way).

I really think both should be synonymed to [editing](/questions/tagged/editing), but because of the prior synonyming it won't allow me to create the tag synonym.  Could we please get this done?

Here's the message I get when I try to create the synonym:

[image: Reverse Synonym stop message]

---

There are 239 questions tagged [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) and it has no wiki.

There are 1861 questions tagged [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) and the tag wiki says:

> Editing is a core, fundamental Stack Exchange value; we allow editing by registered and unregistered users (if peer reviewed).

Comment: I've never been much of a fan toward the -ing endings for tags. How would you feel about directing them all to [meta-tag:edits] (reverse synonym, send editing to edits)?

Comment: @animuson, I'd be fine with that, though I think the verb covers more of what those kind of questions are about.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I added the tag to one of your high-score [meta-tag:editing] posts, so that you probably have sufficient score to suggest a synonym. If my bounty ends in waste, I'll probably do same to some of my own posts, to get a score sufficient for voting on synonym-request

Comment: @gnat, thanks, I already had the score the problem is that the system thinks that there is a reverse synonym thing going on.  I think it is buggy.  It will take at least a moderator to fix.  I've edited in the error message to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went ahead and did this. Results:

- Reversed synonym to [edits](/questions/tagged/edits) ← [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) and merged.
- Added synonym [edits](/questions/tagged/edits) ← [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) and merged.

I also did some other general cleanup of other "edit" tags while I was in the neighborhood:

- Renamed [comment-editing](/questions/tagged/comment-editing) to [comment-edits](/questions/tagged/comment-edits).
- Renamed [serial-editing](/questions/tagged/serial-editing) to [serial-edits](/questions/tagged/serial-edits) and added synonyms [serial-edits](/questions/tagged/serial-edits) ← [batch-edits](/questions/tagged/batch-edits), [edit-floods](/questions/tagged/edit-floods) and merged.
- Renamed [automated-edits](/questions/tagged/automated-edits) to [automatic-edits](/questions/tagged/automatic-edits) to match other "automatic" tags.